# Best way to handle Flat File Import to SQL Server using C#.Net

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application, batch-processing, flat-file

- I wrote a Console Application that reads list of flat files
- and Parse the data type on a row basis
- and inserts records one after other in respective tables.

> there are few Flat Files which contains about **63k records(rows)**.
>   for such files, my program is taking about 6 hours for one file of 63k
>   records to complete.

This is a test data file. In production i have to deal with 100 time more load.

I am worried, if i can do this any better to speed up.

**Can any one suggest a best way to handle this job?**

Work Flow is as below:

1. Read the FlatFile from Local Machine using `File.ReadAllLines("location")`
2. Create a Record Entity object after parsing each field of the row.
3. Insert this current row in to the Entity

**Purpose of making this as console application is,**
this application should be run(scheduled application) on weekly basis 
and there is conditional logic in it, based on some variable there will be

- full table replace or
- update a existing table or
- delete records in table.

Comment: Well I got this working like this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084964/sqlbulkcopy-with-identity-insert-in-destination-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use '[bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)' operation for inserting a huge data into database.

Comment: this wont be help full, I need this to be a console application that i can schedule for weekly process.

Comment: so what the problem? you can create SqlConnection and execute SqlCommand directly in .net console app.

Comment: I am Accepting your answer, as i have done something similar to your suggestion. (SQLBulkCopy)